# Magento - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry, error found

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

When a product upload from Magento admin-panel  then show some error found.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '932-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID',

query was:

```
insert into `mgnc_cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `use_config_backorders`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `is_decimal_divided`)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to insert an entry into the database with a 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID' value of '932-1', but the insert is failing because there is already another entry with that value for the same column. It is failing because there is some kind of constraint on the 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID' column, and looking at the column name, the constraint is likely the UNIQUE constraint, which requires that all database entries have different values for that column.

That being said, you can make the database ignore such entries by using the INSERT IGNORE command. So the query is:

```
insert ignore into `mgnc_cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `use_config_backorders`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `is_decimal_divided`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```